# What datatype should I use for "2020-04-11T19:54:00.0000000Z" in a MySQL SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, timestamp

What time format is `2020-04-11T19:54:00.0000000Z`? Should it be entered in a SQL database as `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, `TIME`, or `YEAR`?

Comment: Looks like some ISO 8601 variant. What DBMS are you using? Tag it.

Comment: The time data format in question is part of a result from an API

Comment: You want to know what datatype to use for it, don't you? For that question it isn't interesting where it came from but in which DBMS it should be stored (data types, especially date/time types vary from DBMS to DBMS). You now tagged phpMyAdmin. But that's just a client, not a DBMS. I assume the DBMS is MySQL. I'm changing the tag for you. If the assumption is wrong please correct it.

Comment: Thank you sticky bit. I'll rephrase the title of the question as well

Answer (score 1):

This is [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The format includes date, time with possible precision of fractions of second, and time zone information.

Basically you should use either DATETIME, or convert to UNSIGNED INT, depending on what you prefer.

The devil is in details. If all the values you receive end with Z, then you can assume you receive datetime in UTC. Just use DATETIME and take care your MySQL server is set up to UTC timezone.

Do you need to store timezone name for later retrieval? In this case, you will need to parse input value into two fields. One field to keep datetime in UTC format and second to store time zone value (MySQL's datetime field type does not store time zone value). Also take care of converting input values to UTC. If you're using MySQL version 8.0.19 or later, [it can do that for you](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

Do take care to set your MySQL server time zone variable to UTC.

Comment: note `TIMESTAMP` and `UNSIGNED INT` have a Y2038 problem currently, consider `UNSIGNED BIGINT` if you go that path. Keep in mind if you do date queries you are replying on implicit conversion if you use integer types.

Comment: Nice mention @danblack. In fact mysql's `select from_unixtime()` function in MySQL 8 does not accept argument > 2147483647  at all. So there is little point to use UNSIGNED INT. MySQL may address this in future versions, as well as changing the size of TIMESTAMP field. That's a piece of technical debt I would worry about in a few years time. Unless @Mike Pistachio has an immediate need to store timestamps that are in far future and he'll prefer to go TIMESTAMP/INT way.